# Desktop computer stuck on Intel boot screen

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My desktop has Windows 7. I tried to install Windows Vista but it was giving an error `0x80070070`. I tried to delete the C: drive and create a new partition.

However when I pressed the delete button it got stuck with no response even after half an hour so I decided to shut it down.

[image]

When I restarted, my PC kept on getting stuck on the Intel icon (see the picture above). I thought there could be a problem in the internal HDD as whenever I disconnected the HDD the PC would work fine, but since there is no HDD it books into Realtek name hardware.

I checked my HDD wire and cable thrice and also changed the SATA cable. I touched the HDD while the PC is running and it's moving with no apparent heat issue. The red light is continuously stable with a dimmed light.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why did you press Del instead of F2 as hinted? If you cannot go into BIOS settings with the drive connected but can do that with the drive disconnected, it's likely the drive has some sort of physical damage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you corrupted your installation of Windows so you will have to make a bootable USB or CD with another installation of Windows or another operating system such as Linux which is free.

Edit: Try formatting the disk.  [Click Me](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-format-hard-drive-in-windows-reset-windows10-3470977/)

Comment: my hard disk is not even showing after cable attached how i supposed tomake any correction in windows???

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had figured out that whats issue due to RAM, I exchange my RAM with someone and now pc works fine. No issue with Windows working fine.